# Problemas con react native: get() is undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, react-native

estoy aprendiendo react native y me tope con un problema raro.Cree una clase Request que lo que hace es hacer request con axio. Luego la paso a un test y obtengo este estrano problema: get() is undefined.

parte del codigo de Reqquest.

```
class Request {
constructor(url, baseURL) {
    this.url = url;
    this.baseURL = baseURL || base;
    this.request = axios.create({ baseURL: this.baseURL, headers });
}

get(){
    this.request.create({ url: this.url});
}
```

Codigo del test:

```
import Request from "./base";

export default new Request('pokemon_stats.json');
```

en fin en la App.js lo llamo de esta forma:

```
test.get().then(res => console.log({ res }));
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: _test.default.get() is undefined

This error is located at:
    in CreateUser (at App.js:14)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in project(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `get` de la clase Request no devuelve nada, por tanto con la ejecución de `test.get()` obtienes un `undefined`.

La solución es añadir un `return` al código:

```
get(){
  return this.request.create({ url: this.url});
}
```

Comment: Gracias bro, pense que habia puesto el return